# open new window as STAThread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am using a `BackGroundWorker` to access some data and read it. But I need to open up a new wpf window inside the code that reads the data. `(synchronous)`

When I am doing this I am getting an error.

I tried adding `[STAThread]` above the functions that opens a new window but this doesn't work.

Method that opens the new window:

```
[STAThread]
int returnColumnStartSelection(string filePath)
{
    ColumnStartSelection css = new ColumnStartSelection(filePath);
    css.ShowDialog();
    return css.lineStart;
}
```

Entry point for the new Window:

```
public ColumnStartSelection(string filePath)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //
    this.Topmost = true;
    this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
}
```

Comment: Do not create and show a window on a background thread. Instead, use the main window's Dispatcher to Invoke an Action that shows the secondary window.

Comment: The exception message you got told you that you are trying to run code that is not thread-safe on a worker thread.  The solution is *not* to try to bypass the message, use Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to ensure the code is safe.

Comment: BGW was created so you *DON'T* have to modify the UI from the background thread. That's what the progress event is for. BGW itself is obsolete since you can do anything it does using Tasks, `Task.Run`, async/await and `IProgress<T>` to construct far more complex asynchronous methods

Comment: BTW there are several dozens of dupcliate questions. The problem isn't STAThread. *No* operating system allows a thread to modify the UI created by *another* thread. There are no "entry points" per window, there is one message pump that handles all windows.

Comment: Didnt helped me at all. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

I stoped using the `BackgroundWorker` and started using `aysnc` and `await`. 
For my `STAThread` problem I build a new Method that creates a new STAThread and the other Thread just waits until a Value change.

```
string selectTable(myDataTable dt)
{
    string column = null;
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        TableSelection ts = new TableSelection(dt);
        ts.ShowDialog();
        column = ts.column;
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();

    while (column == null)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
    try { thread.Abort(); } catch { }

    return column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your question. If not, feel free to correct me.

To open a new window from within the BackgroundWorker_DoWork method, you can use the Dispatcher as mentioned in the comments:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            EmailEnter emailer = new EmailEnter("Transfer", employee);
            emailer.ShowDialog();
        });
```

That is an example from some of my working code. The employee variable is local to the background worker method and is sent to the EmailEnter constructor as a parameter. The window is then opened using .ShowDialog().

I called this at the end of my BackgroundWorker_DoWork method.

In your case, you would want to replace EmailEnter with ColumnStartSelection and pass your filePath variable to it.

Please let me know if you want me to clarify anything.